# Is it possible to make SBT respect Scalatest's DoNoDiscover annotations?

Tags: scala, testing, annotations, sbt, scalatest

I know I can filter which tests to run using `Tests.Filter(s => s.endsWith("Test"))`.

However, Scalatest (and I'm sure other testing frameworks) has an @DoNotDiscover annotation for when running the framework directly.

I was wondering, is there a way to make SBT recognize this annotation?

Thanks

EDIT: I just found out that `Tests.Filter(s => s.endsWith("Test"))` isn't what I want. I have some tests that shouldn't be ran in Jenkins. I would like these tests to not run when I type `sbt test`. However, I would like these tests to run if called directly `sbt test-only some.test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't do it with ScalaTest 1.x, the latest 2.0.M6-SNAP36 should have it supported though:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.10/2.0.M6-SNAP36/

Comment: I'm using 2.0.M6-SNAP20. I'll upgrade and see what happens

Comment: So this does in fact make sbt understand the annotation, but I can't run that specific test with `test-only some.test`. Maybe I'm just asking for too much :D. Oh well, marking as answer since it did answer it.

Comment: According to the scalatest doc for @DoNotDiscover, [Scalatest should be able to run annotated tests if asked explicitly] (http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.M5b/index.html#org.scalatest.DoNotDiscover). So I think this may be another Scalatest-to-sbt bug

Comment: Here's the [discussion on scalatest-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scalatest-users/DoNotDiscover%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false/scalatest-users/l8FK7_I0agU/5ppcItVIsakJ).  Bottom-line, sbt won't run any test marked with @DoNotDiscover (yet)